# Unable to position navigation bar elements correctly in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to make a personal website for myself. The current navbar looks like this.

[image]

I want it to look like this

[image]

This is my `index.js` for this

```
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Nav>
                <NavbarContainer>
                    <NavLogo to='/'>Devang Mukherjee</NavLogo>
                    <MobileIcon>
                        <FaBars />
                    </MobileIcon>
                    <NavMenu>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLinks to='about'>About</NavLinks>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLinks to='experience'>Experience</NavLinks>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLinks to='skills'>Skills</NavLinks>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLinks to='blog'>Blog</NavLinks>
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavBtn>
                            <NavBtnLink to="/contactme"> Contact Me</NavBtnLink>
                        </NavBtn>
                    </NavMenu>
                </NavbarContainer>
            </Nav>
        </>
    )
}
```

I am using react styled components here like `Nav`,`NavbarContainer`,`NavBtnLink`,`NavItem`,`NavBtn`,`NavLinks`

```
export const Nav = styled.nav`
  background: #000;
  height: 80px;
  /* margin-top: -80px;*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;

  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    transition: 0.8s all ease;
  }
`;

export const NavbarContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 24px;
  max-width: 1100px;
`;

export const NavItem = styled.li`
  height: 80px;
`;

export const NavBtn = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;

export const NavLinks = styled(LinkS)`
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;

  &.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #01bf71;
  }
`;

export const NavBtnLink = styled(LinkR)`
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #01bf71;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 22px;
  //margin-left: 222px;
  color: #010606;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;

  &:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
    color: #010606;
  }
`;
```

How can I get the gap between blog and contact me like in the second picture which is responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) in `NavbarContainer`.

It should be something like:

```
export const NavbarContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

Comment: I did that and its still not working, I updated the code in the answer please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap `NavLogo` and `MobileIcon` in a `div`.
2. Take off `NavBtn` from `NavMenu`.
3. Use `justify-content: space-between;`

Follow the link to see result with .html & .css (whitout *ReactJS*):

[postion-navigation-bar-element](https://codesandbox.io/s/postion-navigation-bar-element-vcnnl?file=/index.html)